# how to deploy a custom sub-directory within the project with capistrano?

Tags: ruby, capistrano, capistrano3

I couldn't find a way to do this yet with capistrano, but lets say I have a project like

```
project
project/src
project/Capfile
project/config/deploy.rb
project/config/deploy/production.rb
project/build
project/build/main.js
project/build/other_src.js
```

so the intention is to deploy only what I have within the **/build** sub directory within the project.

I realize I can just move the capistrano files to the **build** directory, but the directory is build and dropped every time I compile the project, so I need to kept the capistrano files within the root dir of the project.

Any advice on how to do it in Capistrano?

Answer (score 0):

I've always deployed the entire project and then pointed my webserver at the relevant subfolder. Alternately, you can write a custom task to rework the data in the release path.